# Understanding routing error (Python)

Tags: python, ubuntu, runtime-error

I'm trying to make a program work that calls files in a specific folder. However, for some reason, I keep getting an error. I'll post the relevant code and error message.

Code:

```
def objmask(inimgs, inwhts, thresh1='20.0', thresh2='2.0', tfdel=True, 
            xceng=3001., yceng=3001., outdir='.', tmpdir='tmp'):
# initial detection of main galaxy with SExtractor for re-centering purposes
    if outdir!='.':
        if not os.path.exists(outdir):
            os.makedirs(outdir)

    if not os.path.exists(tmpdir):
        os.makedirs(tmpdir)
    for c in range(np.size(inimgs)):
        print 'Creating Aperture Run:', c
        subprocess.call(['sex',inimgs[c],'-c','/home/vidur/se_files/gccg.sex',
                         '-CATALOG_NAME','/home/vidur/se_files/_tmp_seobj'+str(c)+'.cat',
                         '-PARAMETERS_NAME','/home/vidur/se_files/gccg_ell.param',
                         '-FILTER_NAME','/home/vidur/se_files/gccg.conv',
                         '-STARNNW_NAME','/home/vidur/se_files/gccg.nnw',
                         '-CHECKIMAGE_TYPE','APERTURES',
                         '-VERBOSE_TYPE','QUIET',
                         '-DETECT_THRESH',thresh1,
                         '-ANALYSIS_THRESH',thresh2,
                         '-WEIGHT_IMAGE',inwhts[c]],shell=True
                         )
```

Error:

```
Creating Aperture Run: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "fetch_swarp2.py", line 110, in objmask
    '-WEIGHT_IMAGE',inwhts[c]],
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have a folder named se_files in my home directory. Its path is /home/username/se_files. This is on Ubuntu, 12.04 32-bit.

Comment: I can't believe someone actually named a program `sex` so the old `man sex` jokes no longer work. Just like `gmake` ruined the old `make love` joke by giving clearer error messages. GNU really isn't Unix. :)

Comment: First, what's the deal with all that code to create `outdir` and `tmpdir` and so on when you don't even pass them to the child process, or do anything else with them?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `subprocess` can't `sex`, presumably because it's not on your PATH.

The [`call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) function won't ever raise an Exception because the program it ran returned failure; it just returns that failure to you as a number. It only raises it it can't run the program in the first place.

You can see the difference pretty easily:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['nosuchprogram'])
[long traceback skipped]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nosuchprogram'
>>> subprocess.call(['ls', 'nosuchfile'])
ls: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
1
```

The first one raises; the second returns `1`.

So, put the absolute path to `sex` in the call, or make sure it's installed properly, or make sure your script is running with the right environment (e.g., maybe you added `/opt/sex/bin` to your `PATH` only in interactive scripts, or you only added it for your own user but you're trying to run the script as `nobody`, or…).